# How to do some keyboard command in .vimrc?

Tags: vim

I want to put a command such as `zz` in .vimrc, so the focus line moves to the center of the screen when started, but I cannot put zz in .vimrc direclty, is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `~/.vimrc` is sourced at the very beginning of Vim startup, where no buffers and windows have been created yet. You need to delay the command until the initialization is done, and the passed argument is loaded and displayed (for an empty buffer, `zz` does nothing). This can be done with an `:autocmd`; the event is `VimEnter`:

```
:autocmd VimEnter * normal! zz
```

The `:normal` is needed because `:autocmd` accepts Ex commands, not normal-mode ones.

Answer (score 1):

The `vimrc` file is for colon commands -- like `:map` and friends. If you want to use a normal mode command like `zz`, you can use the colon command `:normal`. You can use `:normal zz` to do what you want.